# Tomcat 7.0 HTTP post request utf-8 issues with windows server 2008 R2

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat, utf-8, windows-server-2008-r2

I have a very strange issue, I have a web app (JSP file) on Tomcat 7.0 instance. I can't figure out why it is not sending POST UTF-8 request correctly. 
I have installed it on windows server 2008 R2. I have configured all those needed settings in server.xml and web.xml, such as URIEncoding=UTF-8 for  tags and setting filter in web.xml.

inside my JSP, I am calling a .Net web service which accepts POST method:

```
private String urlcallPOST(String content){
    String result="";
    try
{
String urlParameters =  "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" ?>"+
"<SOAP-ENV:Envelope"+
"    xmlns:SOAP-ENV=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\""+
"    xmlns:ns1=\"http://tempuri.org/\">"+
"    <SOAP-ENV:Body>"+
"        <ns1:Message>"+
"            <ns1:contentList>"+
"                <ns1:string>"+content+"</ns1:string>"+
"            </ns1:contentList>"+
"        </ns1:Message>" +
"    </SOAP-ENV:Body>" +
"</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>";


URL url = new URL("http://theIP/webservice.asmx"); 
URLConnection connection =  url.openConnection();          
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/xml; charset=utf-8");
connection.setRequestProperty("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/Message\"");

byte[] buf = urlParameters.getBytes();
DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
os.write(buf, 0, buf.length);


BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new    InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
String line = null;
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    System.out.println(line);
}

reader.close();
os.close();
}

catch(Exception e)
{
}


 return result;
}
```

I have used meta tag and defined charset=utf-8 and also used:

```
request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
```

before any request.
I have created one folder called GetMine inside webapps inside tomcat 7.0.57. and copied this jsp file there. When I call the urlCallPOST method with content="**some utf-8 Arabic text**" it shows **????** inside Tomcat's log folder in stdout file.

The Strange point is that when I create a java project(NOT j2ee or static web) inside **ECLIPSE** and call urlcallPOST. It works fine.

When I saw the result from ECLIPSE was fine, decided to install **WireShark** packet capture tool and check the result and was surprised that when executing code from ECLIPSE, wireshark was showing those Arabic characters in this format: \330\263\330\264 etc. and webservice also returns correct response. but When checked from my JSP executing it, the wireshark was showing those Arabic characters in this format: **?????**

I googled and find this website showing these Arabic encoding: http://www.acc.umu.se/~saasha/charsets/?charset=iso_8859-4&charset=cp1256

I tried hard-coding **\330\263\330\264** inside the content tag of my urlCallPOST method, but still it doesn't show correct characters (some characters were showing correctly!!!!)

**What should I do**? Is this something wrong/bug with windows server 2008 R2's encoding?
I have this exact configuration within Solaris and JBOSS tomcat and it is working fine.

Comment: Don't use the log to test this, as the log is probably being saved as ASCII.  Print it out in some other way to test.

Comment: As I said, I used WireShark and test and it was sending ???? instead of characters.

Comment: please help i am in very time limit.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I find the solution.
You need to add just a little config within tomcat's configuration:
add "-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" and that's all. See the picture below.

[image: Tomcat 7 configuration]

Additionally you have set URIEncoding=UTF-8 within server.xml file.

[image: URI Encoding]